# how to pull from bitbucket into eclipse

Tags: bitbucket

After watching this usful video 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Afd7Li_oAHg

I learnt how to use eclipse to send my project to bitbucket but now imagine that I want to import that project that I have in bitbucket on the the elipse in other computers but I dont know how to do that. I searched the web but could not find any complete material the only thing that I got was that i should do pulling but I could not find anything else.  could u please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suHKgABZuws

or you can watch this one :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koEZ6h0tmn8

Comment: Not really a universal gripe since most people probably don't care, but I hate it when videos are provided *as* answers.  That might work fine for hobbyists or people who work from home but I can't be blasting videos in an open office.  Anything that can be spoken can be typed...